# insert cursor postion in org-structure-template-alist

Tags: org-mode

It's easy to insert source code template in org 9.1 by

it is configured as

```
("s" "#+BEGIN_SRC ?\n#+END_SRC")
```

Of them, ? for cursor position,

unfortunately, it does not work in 9.2

Custormize org-structure-template-alist

org-structure-template-alist

("s" . "src ?\n")

it is dsplayed as:

```
#+begin_src ?\n
#+end_src
```

How could get the ? work properly as cursor position?

Answer (score 0):

Template handling [has changed in org 9.2](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/etc/ORG-NEWS#L418):

> *** Change in the structure template expansion
>
> Org 9.2 comes with a new template expansion mechanism, combining
>   `org-insert-structure-template` bound to `C-c C-,`.
>
> If you customized the `org-structure-template-alist` option manually,
>   you probably need to udpate it, see the docstring for accepted values.
>
> If you prefer using previous patterns, e.g. `<s`, you can activate
>   them again by requiring Org Tempo library:
>
> : (require 'org-tempo)
>
> or add it to `org-modules`.
>
> If you need complex templates, look at the `tempo-define-template`
>   function or at solutions like Yasnippet.

Unless you really need complex templates (and you most probably don't), the easiest thing to do is delete the customization to `org-structure-template-alist` from your init file. The default value should work the way you want. Alternatively, if you have customized this variable (rather than setting it in your init file), do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`org-structure-template-alist`<kbd>RET</kbd>, click on  the `customize` link, click on `Revert` and from the drop-down menu, choose `Erase customizations`; then try `<s` again.